# Select Price field MySQL JSON on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mysql-json

I want to get data that Price is greater than or equal to a specified value (taken from the input).

```
$minPrice = $request->min_price;
$maxPrice = $request->max_price;

$value = Dproduct::where(['status' => 1])->where('price', '>', $minPrice)->get();
```

But the Price is JSON in database, I can't get it. Currencies such as: VND, USD, TWD,...

[image]

All answers are respected!
Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the database column of the type json? and which laravel version are you using? You can use  [json where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#json-where-clauses)

Comment: @Remul I save price is json, my version is 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using laravel 5.7 or greater then you may be able to select within the JSON. See the docs [**here**](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#json-where-clauses) for more details.

**Note:** for this to work you must use json data type for your field in database.

```
$minPrice = $request->min_price;
$maxPrice = $request->max_price;

$value = Dproduct::where(['status' => 1])->where('price->USD', $minPrice)->get();
```

Comment: That is great! Thanks so much :D